# Do local applications or ingestion of lemon eucalyptus oil help treating a tendinitis?

Tags: tendinitis, natural-remedy, epicondylitis

I have read some claims that local applications or ingestions of lemon eucalyptus oil help treating a tendinitis.

Example from Worwood, Valerie Ann. [The Complete Book of Essential Oils and Aromatherapy: Over 600 Natural, Non-toxic & Fragrant Recipes to Create Health• Beauty• A Safe Home Environment](https://books.google.com/books?id=MflOkV2qNAUC&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=lemon+eucalyptus+oil+tendonitis&source=bl&ots=69PMaxbj_7&sig=gDcSRCq8jpWLysVqm2upL3N58cE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwix8-WHz4HKAhUCax4KHa4kBawQ6AEIMTAD#v=onepage&q=lemon%20eucalyptus%20oil%20tendonitis&f=false). New world library, 2012:

[image]

Is there any scientific evidence supporting or infirming the usefulness of local applications or ingestions of lemon eucalyptus oil to treat a tendinitis? I am mostly interested in lateral epicondylopathies of the humerus.

If so, what is the recommended use? (number of applications per day, quantity to use, before/after physical effort, morning/evening, etc.)

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.